Shopware 6 plugin: How to Resolve 'Undefined Array Key' Warning?
I'm working on a Shopware 6 plugin and encountering a warning related to accessing an array key that doesn't exist.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
$customFields = $order->getCustomFields();
$optin = null;
if (array_key_exists('swag_product_reviews_optin', $customFields)) {
    $optin = $customFields['swag_product_reviews_optin'];
}
$text .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;» Optin: ' . $optin;

As you can see, I'm checking if the swag_product_reviews_optin key exists in the $customFields array before attempting to access it. However, I'm still getting the following warning:
Warning: Undefined array key "swag_product_reviews_optin"

Here's the full stack trace:
#0 /home/wokljnlu/sw66demo.wo-kaufen.de/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(178): Swag\ProductReviews\Administration\Controller\SwagProductReviewsTestMailController->orderWhyNot()
#1 /home/wokljnlu/sw66demo.wo-kaufen.de/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(76): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
...

I'm not sure what could be causing this warning, as the code seems to be correctly checking for the key's existence before accessing it.
My question is:
What could be causing this "Undefined array key" warning in Shopware 6, even though I'm checking for the key's existence before accessing it? Is there something I'm missing or a better way to handle this scenario?
This code is executed in a controller action when an admin user triggers a specific route.

I don't see how this code could generate this error. Are you positive this is the offending line?

array_key_exists() raises a warning because $customFields can be null.
You have a choice between isset() and array_key_exists(), it all depends on your specific use case and the requirements of your code. Here are some guidelines to help you decide when to use each function:
Use isset() when you want to check if a variable or an array key is set and not null.
Use array_key_exists() when you specifically want to check if a given key exists in an associative array, regardless of its value.
If you prefer to use isset(), your code can be written as follows:
$customFields = $order->getCustomFields();
$customFieldKey = 'swag_product_reviews_optin';
$optin = null;

if (isset($customFields[$customFieldKey])) {
    $optin = $customFields[$customFieldKey];
}

$text .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;» Optin: ' . $optin;

If you want to use array_key_exists(), your code will look like this:
$customFields = $order->getCustomFields();
$customFieldKey = 'swag_product_reviews_optin';
$optin = null;

if (!empty($customFields) && array_key_exists($customFieldKey, $customFields)) {
    $optin = $customFields[$customFieldKey];
}

$text .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;» Optin: ' . $optin;


Since Shopware 6.5.1.0 there is a helper to retrieve a customField value.
So your code will look like this:
/** @var string|null $optin */
$optin = $order->getCustomFieldsValue('swag_product_reviews_optin');
if (!$optin) {
    return;
}
        
//Your logic

